# Is there a free software that can import excel into mysql on mac?

Tags: mysql, import, mac-os-x, excel

not csv format files, but .xls or .xlsx format excel files, is there any free software for mac, that can import data into mysql?

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure.. I am the author of the following program.
Give it a try and let me know what you think.
I have tried many applications including the excel add-in from MySQL, but was not satisfied with them, so I wrote my own.

The current version of my program is slow (just like the MySQL add-in), doesn't support international characters, and doesn't support command line parameters, but it is free and works well.

http://panofish.net/excel2mysql/

I am working on a much better version which will remedy the aforementioned shortcomings and should be available soon.

Comment: Version 2.0 of Excel2MySQL is available and it is FAST and more importantly 100% accurate.  No longer free, but it is cheap.  http://excel2mysql.net

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried any of the followings. But just sharing with the hope that this may help you...

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/02/27/excel-2011-query-mysql/
http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/excel-2011-mysql-config/

Source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?171,561930,561930

*FYI, MySQL officially introduced a tool namely [MySQL for Excel](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-for-excel.html) (for Windows) to work with Excel.*

> MySQL for Excel allows you to work with a MySQL database from within Microsoft Excel. MySQL data can be imported into Excel, Excel data can be exported into MySQL as a new table or appended to a current table, and MySQL for Excel allows you to edit the MySQL data directly from within Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Save it as `.csv` and then use the mySQL CLI [or other client-side utility] to issue a [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement.

Comment: Agree 1000% using 3rd party software for this type of activity is bound to complicate things more than it needs to.